# json encode doesn't show any result

Tags: php

I'm new to php and i'm building simple android application with php back end. 
 Here is my script. I'm using android Volley library to call this script but this doesn't show anything. Any help appreciated

```
<?php

require("config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

$query = "SELECT company_name,info1,date,hour FROM customer WHERE phone_number = :phone_number ORDER BY id";

$query_params = array (':phone_number' => $_POST['phone_number']);

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}

catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$pnumber = $_POST['phone_number'];
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($row == true) 
{
    $response = $row;
    echo die(json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
}
else {
    $response["phone_number"] = "찾을 수 없음";
    $response["company_name"] = "찾을 수 없음";
    $response["info1"] = "찾을 수 없음";
    $response["date"] = "찾을 수 없음";
    $response["hour"] = "찾을 수 없음";
        die(json_encode(array($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)));
} 
}
?>
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is the contents of `$_POST['phone_number']` before the try block?

Comment: its posting user's phone number like 999-9999-9999

Comment: Are you sure it actually contains that? Can you check?

Comment: how can i check that ?